# settings.ini being used by another program. close other program

Tags: windows-7

Suddenly, got message "settings.ini is being used by another process.  Close other program".  How do I find out what the other program is?  No gadgets either.  I went to task manager and closed the settings.ini running...

Comment: Probably Explorer.exe...

Answer (score 2):

[Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) is your friend.

1. Run Process Explorer (as Administrator if possible - because the process you want to find may not be executed by you)
2. Push <kbd>CTRL-F</kbd>
3. Enter Settings.ini (**wtee.exe on the screehshot is just an example** - you will see a different name.)

   [image: Process Explorer Search]
4. Check the process name, double click the entry and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>. The process will be highlighted on the Process Explorer main window and this is what you want to find.
5. If the process has its own window, find it and close it gracefully. You can quickly find the window by right-clicking on the entry to see if 'window' menu is activated. On this screenshot, the menu is disabled as wtee.exe is a console application.

   [image]
6. If it does not have any visible window or there is no way to gracefully close the process, hit <kbd>DEL</kbd> on Process Explorer window to terminate the process.

   [image: Confirm Kill]
7. Click "OK" and the process will be gone.